# A word meaning "a man who leers at women"

Tags: word-request

I am trying to find an exact translation into English of a word meaning "a man who openly stares at women in a lascivious way". I am aware of several verbs that describe the activity, but no nouns.

I found [ogler](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ogler) but it doesn't sound like a real word for me, and [lecher](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=lecher%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=CgH8VrPEJ4vpapDpmJAH) seems to have too broad a meaning.

Is there another word that's more suitable, and more widely used?

Comment: Maybe perv, pig, or objectifier. Can't think of a specific noun or adjective to describe these men.

Comment: He is a _creep._  He may be a pervert, or a stalker - we don't know that.  But he is definitely a creep.....Or at least I think so.  Probably should let a woman weigh in, since they would be most aware of the gradations on the _awkward guy_ <---> _dangerous pervert_ spectrum

Comment: Lecher is the closest word I can think of (when I was a young coed we called them "leches", e.g. "Ew, Professor Y is such a lech.") It does have a connotation of an older man leering/visibly lusting after younger women though.

Comment: Oh, there's also voyeurs and peeping toms, but those emphasize the secretly watching part. Leering seems more overt.

Comment: @Adam, thank you for your suggestions, but I am not interested in expressing the degree of odiousness: I want a specific word for somebody that stares openly at women in a lascivious way.

Comment: @JavaLatte  Understood - you want a word for one specific type of odious - I was just saying that a woman might be more attuned to which word goes with which type of odious than I am.

Comment: Thanks @ColleenV, I think that you may have hit pay dirt. I initially thought of that (I remember vividly a guy that the term was used about- a forty-ish lawyer who openly stared at young women in front of his wife), but I searched for "letch" and got too broad a definition. Still open to other suggestions though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the British slang noun [*Lech*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/lech)

A Lech is a man who looks at women in an openly lecherous manner.  Indeed the word derives from lecherous.

Comment: I also know this word from the US.

Answer (score 1):

***Peeper*** who is *a person who peeps at someone or something, especially in a voyeuristic way* as in

> He's looking up Sarah's skirt! Damn, he's such a peeper.

***voyeur*** who is *a person who gains sexual pleasure from watching others when they are naked or engaged in sexual activity.* as in

> he stood transfixed, a voyeur feasting on the swell of her buttocks.

I usually hear people describe the person acting like this as a ***pervert*** or simply *perv* as in

> Stop ​looking down my ​dress, you perv.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [ogler](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/ogler) is correct. But because you were looking for something else.. [Voyeur](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/voyeur) It is defined as:

> a viewer who enjoys seeing the sex acts or sex organs of others

Comment: The O.P. asked for a person who _openly_ stares, and oftentimes _voyeur_ has overtones of [watching in secret](https://www.wordnik.com/words/voyeur). Still, a worthy candidate word to consider.